# Laravel number comparison in 'where' not working

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 app, and am having trouble with a 'where' with a numerical comparison.
Specifically I am trying to do:

```
{{\App\Items::all()->where('paid_price','>',0)->count()}}
```

The SQL 'type' of paid_price is 'decimal(8,2)'.
There are several Item rows where the paid_price is in fact greater than zero, but the code above just yields 0. Stuff like the below which don't rely on numerical comparisons works just fine - can you give me any tips on why the > doesn't work? Thanks a lot

```
{{\App\Items::all()->where('other_column','some_value')->count()}}
```

The code for my Items class is below:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Items extends Model {
protected $fillable =['gateway','paid_price','payment_date','auth_date','charge_date','refunded_date'];
protected $dates = ['payment_date','auth_date','charge_date','refunded_date'];
public function setUserIdAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['user_id'] = $value ?: null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison in your `where` clause should work correctly. Just remove the `all()`.

```
\App\Items::where('paid_price','>',0)->count()
```

If you specify `all()`, it will first return an array of `Items` objects, so when you called `where()` function, it will lead to wrong query on the array returned

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the SQL using the method `toSql()` so you can see the SQL query and you can execute it from a client or a frontend like MySQL Workbench:

```
{{ \App\Items::all()->where('paid_price','>',0)->count()->toSql() }}
```